# How to take Backup of Data when user uninstall app and re-install app all data recover

Tags: android

I am try to take backup of my sqlite database when user uninstall app. and recover that sqlite data when user Re-install app. I am try custom BackupAgentHelper but i am install app and insert data of sqlite database and then uninstall app. and reinstall app then my database is empty. If any one have solution of this issue send me source code of this

Comment: please post your DbBackupHelper class, it is maybe a problem in your code

Comment: You are not notified when your app is being uninstalled. `BackupAgentHelper` is not invoked at the time an app is uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the database to the SD Card. However, you will lose access to the database if the user changes the SD Card .

Another option would be to back it up to a server at regular intervals.

Answer (score -1):

You can save data on Google drive. 
Use App Folder service

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder

Comment: How to use this can u tell me step by step